# what is root layout?

Tags: android, fragment

I have always had problem with the root layout. in the paragraph below, **you must return a View from this method that is the root of your fragment's layout**.

onCreateView()
The system calls this when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time. To draw a UI for your fragment, you must return a View from this method that is the **root of your fragment's layout**. You can return null if the fragment does not provide a UI.

what is the root of a fragment's layout? is it the main_activity.xml or the layout file that define this specific fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the layout file which needs to be displayed in the `Fragment`. We can it as a parent of all the views and layout that need's to be displayed in the `Fragment`

There must be only one root element and it must contain the xmlns:android attribute with the android namespace as shown. `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Hope this helps :)

**Added:** The onCreateView() method in your case should return layout file that define this specific fragment

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

- `Fragments` were built to utilize the extra space remaining on the Pads.
- In case of **Mobile phones** we move from One `Activity` to Another, But in case of `Pads` when we use `Fragments` it always **runs in context** of an `Activity`.
- The `Fragment` can be `Dynamically` **added and removed** from an `Activity`.
- On the `onCreateView()` method the `Fragments View` is **inflated** on the `Root View`, and this is what is to `returned` from that method.

Answer (score 0):

The fragment most likely exists as a part of a parent (or root) layout. My interpretation of the paragraph is that your highest-level layout in main_activity.xml would be the root layout.

Comment: `main_activity.xml` is a file, to be exact.